# JDO Batch PUT from Memcache

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, put

In an effort to reduce the number of datastore PUTs I am consuming I 
wish to use the memcache much more frequently. The idea being to store 
entities in the memcache for n minutes before writing all entities to 
the datastore and clearing the cache.

I have two questions:

Is there a way to batch PUT every entity in the cache? I believe 
makePersistentAll() is not really batch saving but rather saving each 
individually is it not?

Secondly is there a "callback" function you can place on entities as 
you place them in the memcache? I.e. If I add an entity to the cache 
(with a 2 minute expiration delta) can I tell AppEngine to save the 
entity to the datastore when it is evicted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

makePersistentAll does indeed do a batch PUT, which the log ought to tell you clear enough

Comment: Thanks DataNucleus.

One remaining question I have is, calling entrySet() on my cache to 
get every entity saved in the cache and passing that to 
makePersistentAll() is fine; however, the api docs state: "If the map 
is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress the results 
of the iteration are undefined". My cache is updated very frequently 
so the map will be modified. So how do you prevent this from happening 
and persist each entity in the cache to the datastore? 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to fetch the entire contents of memcache in App Engine. In any case, this is a bad idea - items can be evicted from memcache at any time, including between when you inserted them and when you tried to write the data to the datastore. Instead, use memcache as a read cache, and write data to the datastore immediately (using batch operations when possible).